# Kubernetes Leader Election Fails with Unit Test

Tags: scala, kubernetes, scalatest, leader-election

I'm trying out some leader election logic in one of my Microservice using the Kubernetes fabirc java client. Here is what I came up with:

```
def testAndAssertSingleLeader(client: KubernetesClient, id: String, lock: Lock): Assertion = {
        // Given
    val leaderLatch = new CountDownLatch(1)
    val newLeaderRecord = new AtomicReference[String]
    val stoppedLeading = new CountDownLatch(1)
    val executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor
    val leaderCallback = new LeaderCallbacks(
      () => {
        println("I am the leader now, performing the batch job.")
        leaderLatch.countDown()
      },
      () => {
        println("I am no longer the leader.")
        stoppedLeading.countDown()
      },
      (newLeader: String) => {
        println(s"A new leader is elected: $newLeader")
        newLeaderRecord.set(newLeader)
      })
    val leaderElectionConfig = new LeaderElectionConfig(
      lock,
      Duration.ofSeconds(15L),
      Duration.ofSeconds(10L),
      Duration.ofSeconds(2L),
      leaderCallback,
      true,
      "Integration test leader election configuration"
    )
    // When
    val leaderElectorTask = executorService.submit(
      () => assertThrows(
        classOf[InterruptedException],
        () => client.leaderElector.withConfig(leaderElectionConfig).build().run()
      )
    )
    // Then
    println(leaderLatch.getCount)
    assert(leaderLatch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    assert(id == newLeaderRecord.get)
    assert(0 == leaderLatch.getCount)
    leaderElectorTask.cancel(true)
    executorService.shutdownNow
    assert(executorService.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    assert(stoppedLeading.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  }

  "K8sLeaderElection" should "create a lease lock" in {
    // Given
    server.expect
      .post
      .withPath("/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/namespace/leases")
      .andReturn(200, null)
      .once
    // When - Then
    testAndAssertSingleLeader(client, "lead-lease", new LeaseLock("namespace", "name", "lead-lease"))
  }
```

I just adapted the code that I found on the fabric GitHub and converted that to Scala as it can be seen. When I ran my unit test, I see the following:

```
Testing started at 22:39 ...


Oct 24, 2023 10:39:31 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 execute
INFO: MockWebServer[51585] starting to accept connections
22:39:31.833 [ScalaTest-run] DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils - Using httpclient io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientFactory factory


22:39:42.108 [ScalaTest-run] DEBUG io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.impl.BaseClient - The client and associated httpclient io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.okhttp.OkHttpClientImpl have been closed, the usage of this or any client using the httpclient will not work after this

1
Oct 24, 2023 10:39:42 PM okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$2 acceptConnections

INFO: MockWebServer[51585] done accepting connections: Socket closed

leaderLatch.await(10L, SECONDS) was false
ScalaTestFailureLocation: com.openelectrons.cpo.k8s.K8sLeaderElectionSpec at (K8sLeaderElectionSpec.scala:137)
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: leaderLatch.await(10L, SECONDS) was false
    at org.scalatest.Assertions.newAssertionFailedException(Assertions.scala:472)
    at org.scalatest.Assertions.newAssertionFailedException$(Assertions.scala:471)
    at org.scalatest.Assertions$.newAssertionFailedException(Assertions.scala:1231)
    at org.scalatest.Assertions$AssertionsHelper.macroAssert(Assertions.scala:1295)
    at com.openelectrons.cpo.k8s.K8sLeaderElectionSpec.testAndAssertSingleLeader(K8sLeaderElectionSpec.scala:137)
    at com.openelectrons.cpo.k8s.K8sLeaderElectionSpec.$anonfun$new$2(K8sLeaderElectionSpec.scala:154)
```

I have the following dependencies in my build.sbt:

```
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.9" % Test,
  "org.mockito" %% "mockito-scala" % "1.16.46" % Test,
  "org.bouncycastle" % "bcpkix-jdk15on" % "1.68" % Test,
  "io.fabric8" % "kubernetes-server-mock" % "6.9.0" % Test exclude("com.fasterxml.jackson.core", "jackson-databind")
```

What am I doing wrong? I was expecting that I get to see the println statement showing me that a leader is elected and after the lease time, I get to see another message from the callback that it is no longer the leader.

Comment: Wild guess: you're using the same client in multiple test cases, and when one of the cases is done it closes the client before the others are done.

Comment: I'm running the test individually, so that cannot be the cause.

Comment: Could you share your build.sbt, and the full class of the test you wrote? If there is any other file involved share it in the post. Providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help us to help you

Comment: I have added the dependencies that I use. The two methods are all what I have in the test class,